# Firebase realtime databae not working, setValue

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I made sample by tutorial 
'https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/?hl=ko' for Firebase realtime database

But I cannot see any data after `onDataChanged` 'EventValueListner'

Can you explain why that is?

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
// Read from the database
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + value);
    }

   @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

It is my code.

What is my fault?

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong with your code. Do you see any messages on the logcat output?

Comment: After seeing the exact same code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742714/firebase-realtimedatabase-is-not-working-now), I wonder if you simply don't have a network connection. That is the only case I can quickly think of then neither `onDataChange()` nor `onCancelled()` will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this example will insert new user data in firebase db.

```
 FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference usersTable;
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    usersTable = database.getReference("Users");
    /*we work here */
    usersTable.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(phoneEditText.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Number already register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Users users = new Users(nameEditText.getText().toString(),passwordEditTex.getText().toString(),phoneEditText.getText().toString());
                            usersTable.child(phoneEditText.getText().toString()).setValue(users);
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Signup Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

[image: sample database]

hope this will help you

Comment: I am sorry for that. I found resolution for that. It is problem for location of china.

Comment: @KaanKoca can you please elaborate on that? I'm having a similar problem.